# AngularJS - simple partial not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm unable to get my partial to load with angular 1.3. I've seen the common mistakes such as not loading angular-route.js, or specifying 'ngRoute' in my app module. I don't see any errors in the console. I've looked at all the 'partials not loading' posts, and they don't seem to apply here. Any idea what's going on here? Thanks!

index.html

```
<html ng-app="App">
<head></head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">

<div ng-view=""></div>

<script src="scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', 
            {
                controller: 'MainController',
                templateURL: './partials/test.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

}());
```

controllers.js

```
(function() {
    var MainController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.model = {
            message: 'Aaarrrgh!'
        };
    };
    MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module('App').controller('MainController',  MainController);    
}());
```

test.html (my partial)

```
<h1>{{model.message}}</h1>
```

Where I should see my content, I see an html comment:

```
<!-- ngView: -->
```

Comment: inspect the actual ajax request in network tab of console...see what clues it can give you

Comment: Using `ng-controller` with `ng-view` seems wrong. Just remove the `ng-controller` attribute from your `<body>` tag

Comment: To be clear, using `ng-controller` on a parent of an `ng-view` is not wrong. It's a very common implementation most often seen when you need an application level controller that is independent of whatever the active view is. In this example though, `$routeProvider` is already configured to inject `MainController` into the view, so the `ng-controller="MainController"` on the `<body>` tag seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `templateURL` to `templateUrl`